# YouTube Data API - 401 GoogleAccountCredential Invalid Credential

Tags: android, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube Data API in my app, and for some reason, sometimes I get an error, when user tries to upload a video.

Here it is:

```
D/Test    (28216): 401 Unauthorized
D/Test    (28216): {
D/Test    (28216):   "code" : 401,
D/Test    (28216):   "errors" : [ {
D/Test    (28216):     "domain" : "global",
D/Test    (28216):     "location" : "Authorization",
D/Test    (28216):     "locationType" : "header",
D/Test    (28216):     "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
D/Test    (28216):     "reason" : "authError"
D/Test    (28216):   } ],
D/Test    (28216):   "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
D/Test    (28216): }
```

I am authorizating user using GoogleAccountCredential like this:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
ls.add(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY);
ls.add(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD);
ls.add(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_FORCE_SSL);
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(c, ls);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(name);
```

And I am not sure, what I'm doing wrong, because the error shows up very randomly, and only to some accounts, for e.g. on my phone the error never showed up, but on other people's devices yes.

Does anyone know how I can ensure this error won't show up, or at least how to fix the credentials after the error is shown?